# Cartesian product of two tables not working as expected in MySQL but fine with SQlitee?

Tags: mysql, join, sqlite

I was practising some sql joins and decided to create a schema online rather than using my local database on sql fiddle. My schema is pretty simple

```
table 1 (5 entries): (emp->{id,name,dep})
table 2 (4 entries): (dep->{id,name})
```

I was supposed to write one inner join on `dep` column which worked with SQLite, but when I tried the same query with MySQL it failed. So in order to investigate, I just checked the Cartesian product of two tables for both the databases.

I tried this query

```
select * from dep a,emp b
```

in both databases.

In SQLite, it correctly return 20 entries with 5 columns in it. But in MySQL, it is returning correctly 20 entries but only 3 columns in it `(id,name,did)`. So this explains why the join was breaking earlier.

I can't understand how can this Cartesian product be incorrect? Can someone please explain to me, what is going wrong in MySQL case?

[MySQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/343925/6/0)

[SQLite fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/34392/8/0)

Comment: Why don't you specify the columns you want?

Comment: Can you show us the query that was "breaking"?

Comment: From what I know, MySQL returns 5 columns, too. Some intermediate layers that you may be using (PHP, SQL-Fiddle, whatever) have issues though when the result set has 2 columns with the same name (alias). That explains why you see 3 columns. Fix your `SELECT` list with explicit column names and alias them so all 5 columns in the result have different names.

Answer (score 2):

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.6.15 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>  use test
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE emp
    ->  (
    ->      id int primary key,
    ->      name varchar(20),
    ->      did int
    ->     );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.45 sec)

mysql>
mysql>
mysql>
mysql> CREATE TABLE dep
    ->  (
    ->      id int primary key,
    ->      name varchar(20)
    ->     );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.35 sec)

mysql>
mysql> INSERT INTO dep
    -> VALUES
    -> (1,'lakers'),
    -> (2,'spurs'),
    -> (3,'sixers'),
    -> (4,'pacers'),
    -> (5,'warriors')
    ->
    -> ;
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> INSERT INTO emp
    -> VALUES
    -> (1,'rohit',1),
    -> (2,'amit',2),
    -> (3,'haris',3),
    -> (4,'eti',4)
    -> ;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

I ran your query without aliases

```
mysql> select * from dep,emp;
+----+----------+----+-------+------+
| id | name     | id | name  | did  |
+----+----------+----+-------+------+
|  1 | lakers   |  1 | rohit |    1 |
|  1 | lakers   |  2 | amit  |    2 |
|  1 | lakers   |  3 | haris |    3 |
|  1 | lakers   |  4 | eti   |    4 |
|  2 | spurs    |  1 | rohit |    1 |
|  2 | spurs    |  2 | amit  |    2 |
|  2 | spurs    |  3 | haris |    3 |
|  2 | spurs    |  4 | eti   |    4 |
|  3 | sixers   |  1 | rohit |    1 |
|  3 | sixers   |  2 | amit  |    2 |
|  3 | sixers   |  3 | haris |    3 |
|  3 | sixers   |  4 | eti   |    4 |
|  4 | pacers   |  1 | rohit |    1 |
|  4 | pacers   |  2 | amit  |    2 |
|  4 | pacers   |  3 | haris |    3 |
|  4 | pacers   |  4 | eti   |    4 |
|  5 | warriors |  1 | rohit |    1 |
|  5 | warriors |  2 | amit  |    2 |
|  5 | warriors |  3 | haris |    3 |
|  5 | warriors |  4 | eti   |    4 |
+----+----------+----+-------+------+
20 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

I ran your query as you gave it, with aliases

```
mysql> select * from dep a,emp b;
+----+----------+----+-------+------+
| id | name     | id | name  | did  |
+----+----------+----+-------+------+
|  1 | lakers   |  1 | rohit |    1 |
|  1 | lakers   |  2 | amit  |    2 |
|  1 | lakers   |  3 | haris |    3 |
|  1 | lakers   |  4 | eti   |    4 |
|  2 | spurs    |  1 | rohit |    1 |
|  2 | spurs    |  2 | amit  |    2 |
|  2 | spurs    |  3 | haris |    3 |
|  2 | spurs    |  4 | eti   |    4 |
|  3 | sixers   |  1 | rohit |    1 |
|  3 | sixers   |  2 | amit  |    2 |
|  3 | sixers   |  3 | haris |    3 |
|  3 | sixers   |  4 | eti   |    4 |
|  4 | pacers   |  1 | rohit |    1 |
|  4 | pacers   |  2 | amit  |    2 |
|  4 | pacers   |  3 | haris |    3 |
|  4 | pacers   |  4 | eti   |    4 |
|  5 | warriors |  1 | rohit |    1 |
|  5 | warriors |  2 | amit  |    2 |
|  5 | warriors |  3 | haris |    3 |
|  5 | warriors |  4 | eti   |    4 |
+----+----------+----+-------+------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I ran your query with aliases in the `SELECT` clause as well as the `FROM` clause

```
mysql> select a.*,b.* from dep a,emp b;
+----+----------+----+-------+------+
| id | name     | id | name  | did  |
+----+----------+----+-------+------+
|  1 | lakers   |  1 | rohit |    1 |
|  1 | lakers   |  2 | amit  |    2 |
|  1 | lakers   |  3 | haris |    3 |
|  1 | lakers   |  4 | eti   |    4 |
|  2 | spurs    |  1 | rohit |    1 |
|  2 | spurs    |  2 | amit  |    2 |
|  2 | spurs    |  3 | haris |    3 |
|  2 | spurs    |  4 | eti   |    4 |
|  3 | sixers   |  1 | rohit |    1 |
|  3 | sixers   |  2 | amit  |    2 |
|  3 | sixers   |  3 | haris |    3 |
|  3 | sixers   |  4 | eti   |    4 |
|  4 | pacers   |  1 | rohit |    1 |
|  4 | pacers   |  2 | amit  |    2 |
|  4 | pacers   |  3 | haris |    3 |
|  4 | pacers   |  4 | eti   |    4 |
|  5 | warriors |  1 | rohit |    1 |
|  5 | warriors |  2 | amit  |    2 |
|  5 | warriors |  3 | haris |    3 |
|  5 | warriors |  4 | eti   |    4 |
+----+----------+----+-------+------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I just ran these in MySQL 5.6.15 on my Windows 8 Laptop. It works fine with and without aliases. It might be SQL Fiddle that has the problem in this instance with a MySQL Cartesian Product.

Comment: Indeed, this is an issue between SQL-Fiddle and MySQL, when two columns in the result have the same alias. Nothing to do with the cross product, only a side effect of using `select *` with more than one tables. See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/343925/8)